# ImageView with Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, imageview

I have a GridView displaying thumbnails using ImageViews. I am displaying a default image while the thumbnail images are being downloaded from the background(inspired from native applications) i.e. the getView() of my adapter class returns a default Bitmap first and then runs a background thread and replaces the default with actual later.

GridViews in iPhone application display a spinner (Animated GIF) instead of default image.

How can a similar thing be achieved in Android?

Comment: WebImageView of DroidFu library does a similar thing

Answer (score 0):

As Raj commented, get DroidFu's `WebImageView` [here](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/).